# add event in dynamic component created in the bean jsf

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Good day, so guys, what I'm wanting to do is the following, I add a HtmlSelectOneMenu via bean in JSF page, and like it when the guy changed his value, HtmlSelectOneMenu him to add another, add the HtmlSelectOneMenu'm getting no problem, however like to know how do I add an event to them via BEAN course ehehee

```
HtmlSelectOneMenu select = new HtmlSelectOneMenu();
        HtmlOutputLabel lblData = new HtmlOutputLabel();
        lblData.setValue(list.get(contador).getItem().getNome());
        UISelectItem item = new UISelectItem();
        item.setItemLabel("NÃO");
        item.setItemValue(false);
        UISelectItem item2 = new UISelectItem();
        item2.setItemLabel("SIM");
        item2.setItemValue(true);
        select.getChildren().add(item);
        select.getChildren().add(item2);
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ELContext elContext = context.getELContext();
        Application app = context.getApplication();
        ExpressionFactory expressionFactory = app.getExpressionFactory();
        ValueExpression ve = expressionFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, "#{projetoBean.qualRespondeu}", String.class);
        select.setValueExpression("valeu", ve);
        UIPanel container = (UIPanel) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(":formProjeto:painel");
        container.getChildren().add(lblData);
        container.getChildren().add(select);
        contador++;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for answers Kolossus however, decided as follows:

```
   AjaxBehavior ajax = new AjaxBehavior();
ajax.setAsync(true);
ajax.setUpdate(":formProjeto");
MethodExpression ex = expressionFactory.createMethodExpression(elContext, "#{projetoBean.adicionaPergunta()}", null, new Class[]{});
ajax.addAjaxBehaviorListener(new AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl(ex, ex));
select.addClientBehavior("change", ajax);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

1. Create the AjaxBehaviorListener (the actual processing of the event):

   ```
   MyAjaxBehaviorListener implements AjaxBehaviorListener{

         @Override
         public void processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorEvent e) throws AbortProcessingException {
         //perform the event processing here

         }


   }
   ```
2. Attach the listener to an `AjaxBehavior`

   ```
    AjaxBehavior ajaxBehavior = (AjaxBehavior) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication() .createBehavior(AjaxBehavior.BEHAVIOR_ID);
    MyAjaxBehaviorListener listener = new MyAjaxBehaviorListener();
    ajaxBehavior.setExecute(Collections.singletonList("@this")); //sets the execute attribute of the event handler
    ajaxBehavior.addAjaxBehaviorListener(listener);
   ```
3. Attach the `AjaxBehavior` to the component

   ```
   item.addClientBehavior("change",ajaxBehavior); //set the triggering event to "change"
   ```

Comment: Thanks for answers Kolossus however I had already found a solution.